# Can you tell a client that he's being overcharged which might put the service provider out of business?

Tags: gezel-stealing, business, lashon-hara-slander

Are there any issues involved with telling a client that a service they are using is overpriced and that a competitor will give them a much cheaper option? Let's assume all the parties are Jewish (client, service #1, competitor service).

Comment: It may be G'neivas Daas not to tell him.

Comment: How are you stealing anything if you're simply a third party?

Comment: I'm uncertain if the focus of your question delves into a possible *Lashon Hara* concern. If it does (please clarify), AFAIK, this is a "to'elet" situation which may allow you to perform this action.

Comment: @AniYodea The OP said "a client". If you are supposed to be advising him, then you must advise him honestly. There is a story about a Rav who was asked by a shul who would be the best Rabbi (when they were looking for a new Rav). He considered and gave the name. That rav came to him and asked if he should take it and he answered "no". When the shul committee came back and asked why, he explained that this rav would be best for the shul, **but** it was not the best fir for the rav. When asked, he had to answer honestly what would be best for the person asking.

Comment: "to'elet" is very tricky. You're benefiting one person while doing a detriment to another...

Comment: G'neivas Daas is withholding knowledge from someone to their detriment.

Comment: @AniYodea Note that the question involves a client being given advice. The *to'elet* would be to give the correct advice to prevent damage to the person you are advising.